# keypress event in Angular 2 RC-5 is not working in Android browsers

Tags: angular

```
<input autocomplete="off" (keypress) = "validateNumber($event)">

validateNumber(event) {
    var charCode = (event.which) ? event.which : event.keyCode;
    if (event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 39) {
       return true;
    }
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
       return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Why keypress event is not firing in Android browsers?

Comment: which browser you are using? specific to any browser or all browser?

Comment: on a unrelated sidenote angular2 has been released. why rc-5 now?

Answer (score 1):

***(keypress)*** should work.

If its not working you should try ***(keyup)*** instead.

```
<input autocomplete="off" (keyup) = "validateNumber($event)">
```

Here both are working with ***chrome***.

- https://plnkr.co/edit/J3rSaIxb4dqt6HbDTAs7?p=preview

**NOTE**: If you have any specific issue, let us know.